# C# Forms - Scrolling RichTextBox past an incomplete last line

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I have an application that periodically displays the message

```
Waiting...
```

at the beginning of a new line in a RichTextBox and then after some arbitrary delay adds Done after the three dots, so the end result will look something like

```
Waiting...Done
```

The problem is that the scroll does not occur until after I've added Done followed by a newline, so I don't get to see just the Waiting... part unless I manually use the vertical scroll bar.  How would I cause the scroll to occur before I add Done but still leave the caret at the end of the ...?

My current code is below.  I call MyFunction first to display the Waiting... message and then later on to complete the line with the Done part.

```
     void MyFunction(string newText)
     {
        myRichTextBox.SelectionStart = myRichTextBox.TextLength + 1;
        myRichTextBox.SelectedText = newText;
        myRichTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
        if (newText == "Waiting...")
        {
           // Scroll down so Waiting... message is visible but
           // leave caret at the end of Waiting... so Done will
           // be on the same line.
        }
     }
```

Comment: As far as I see, you code is basically doing the same thing as `richTextBox1.AppendText("Something ... \n");richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();`. What's the problem?

Comment: Reza, the problem is as I explained in my post.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking or your code doesn't reproduce the problem. As I run your code, it scrolls well and shows the last added line.

Comment: Just to make sure you are doing the same thing as I am, write a bunch of lines until the text box starts scrolling (maybe that's the detail I left out of my description).  Then write something else that does not end with a newline.  Can you see what you just wrote without manually pulling the vertical scroll bar down?  I can't, but I need to and I will eventually need to write something else after it on the same line.

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced. Just try `richTextBox1.AppendText("Waiting ...")` and then immediately `richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();`.

Comment: Reza, thanks for your suggestions.  I did try exactly as you suggested but I'm still having the same issue.  Possibly there's something else going on that I'm not aware of so I'll have to write a dedicated simple application just to test this particular thing and see if it still happens.

Comment: _after some arbitrary delay_ explain this!! Maybe you tie up the UI thread?

Comment: TaW - The delay is anywhere from 10 seconds to 10 years.  It doesn't matter because MyFunction gets called via periodic timer event.